# web safe colours?

Tags: language-agnostic

Is it still relevant to consider these? I don't do much work on the graphics side of things, but recently I set the background colour of a webpage (using CSS) to the same background colour used within images on the page. #312F32. it looked fine on different machines in the office, but at home on my shinny new mac (and a few others since) there was definitely a noticeable difference between the two.

can someone give me a web colour 101 reminder course? :>

---

Reference:

- For an e.g. [this site indicates if a chosen colour is web safe or not.](http://www.computerhope.com/cgi-bin/htmlcolor.pl?c=F9966B)

Comment: What browsers are you seeing problems in?  What image format?

Answer (score 5):

personally I feel that it's not really of that much of importance, since nowadays modern browsers can render colours properly. What is important is that your background image colour should be the same as the background colour.

different of colour between monitors might just be that the monitor settings are different. so you don't have to worry that much.

what's really important for web designs is that your design have to be appealing.

Answer (score 3):

> is it still relevant to consider these?

No. To be honest there was never a truly ‘web-safe’ palette, in that many systems had different colour depths and palettes even in the days when a Windows machine running in 8-bit colour was the norm.

Today there's very little still running an 8-bit palette, and those things that do aren't necessarily using the same one.

> it looked fine on different machines in the office, but at home on my shinny new mac (and a few others since) there was definitely a noticable difference between the two.

A shiny new Mac will definitely be running in full colour like everyone else, so it's not a palette problem.

Was the image a PNG? If so, you've probably got a [gamma problem](http://xdeb.org/node/678) causing colour shifts on different platforms. PNGs for the web should be saved without a gAMA chunk to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to remember it for me:  Multiples of 0x33 at each byte.  E.g. 0x333333, 0x330099, 0xFFFFFF, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The web-safe palette hasn't been relevant for at least five years, IMO. What you're seeing is probably color profile correction in PNGs with embedded color profiles. Some browsers (Firefox 3+, and probably Safari?) read these profiles and attempt to display the image as it was originally created (i.e. as if you were looking at it on the image creator's monitor). This can result in a visual mismatch between "pure" colors in a PNG and rendered HTML colors (e.g. via CSS style)

This is awesome for graphic designers who need to precisely match colors between multiple devices like monitors, scanners and high-end printers. It kinda sorta sucks for everyone else.

The easiest way to prevent this happening (in most cases) is to turn off color correction in your image editor and don't export PNGs (or JPGs) with embedded color profiles. Let the user's monitor guess how to display the image -- usually at the same color profile as everything else on the page.

To ensure that what you see on **your** screen approximates the most common color settings, use a common color correction profile like sRGB or sRGB IEC61966, and keep a relatively "steep" gamma, between 2.0 and 2.3. (Most PCs have a gamma of ~2.2). **Don't** calibrate your monitor unless you're sending graphic files between devices.

Extra credit reading:

- [Color correction for images in Firefox 3.5](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/color-correction/)

  [PNG color test](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/png-colortest.html)

  [The Sad Story of PNG Gamma "correction."](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/png-gamma/)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing differences between your Shiny New Mac and the monitors at work (or many other places) is a difference in monitor [color gamut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamut):

The Mac, and higher-end monitors have better [color gamut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth) than typical consumer-grade monitors.  In my research, a typical Acer or similar monitor had a color gamut of 78%, while a higher-end monitor covers 96% of the [Adobe RGB color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_RGB_color_space).  I have a nice [NEC with 96% color gamut](http://www.nec-display.com/ap/en_display/p221w/index.html) monitor right next to an Acer X223W (78% color gamut), and the difference is simply amazing as I slide an image or website across from one to the other.  Colors appear where there were none, and the image is simply more vibrant and alive.

Answer (score 0):

1) #312F32 is not a 'web safe colour' to start with. Web safe colours are in multiples of 33's such as #333333, #003366, #ff3300 (f=15).

2) The difference in monitors and how they display colours: I had a PC and Mac side by side trying to match the colour in an image with a webpage navbar. I ran into the same problem as you. Even though the colour picker on each computer agreed with what colour was in the image, neither monitor looked exactly right once I updated the navbar colour.

3) Suggestion: sometimes you have to find a happy medium or work with darker shades where you do not notice the colour differences.